# Recognising a chess piece with bitboards

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, chess, bitboard

When the chessboard is stored in a variety of bitboards, how do modern chess engines recognise what type/side piece is situated on a particular cell? I'm having problems with this, since to find out what type/side piece a particular bit is, I have to always do:

```
if((bit_check & occupied) == 0ULL) ... // empty
else if((bit_check & white) != 0ULL) // white
    if((bit_check & white_pawns) != 0ULL) ... // white pawns
    else if((bit_check & white_rooks) != 0ULL) ... // white rooks
    ....
    else if((bit_check & white_kings) != 0ULL) ... // white kings
else if((bit_check & black) != 0ULL) // black
    if((bit_check & black_pawns) != 0ULL) ... // black pawns
    ....
    else if((bit_check) & black_kings) != 0ULL) ... // black kings
```

This is quite a tedious process and it has to be done quite a few times (for example, during move generation to see what is being captured). I'm not sure if I should just go with this or whether it would be faster to simply create a 64 array of type `Piece[64]`, which will inherently store the piece type.

Which would be better, considering it will have to be millions of times, for capture analysis in the search functions. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: What about putting that test cascade into a separate function, instead of repeating the code all times you need it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That I know, this is about operation time, not the looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit check itself is fast; I'd be worried mostly about the branching.

Instead, consider `uint64_t bitboards[12]` as an array of the 12 bitboards for all pieces. This is now contiguous in memory and can be scanned in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 12; ++i)
{
  if (bitboards[i] && bit_check) return i;
}
return -1; // empty.
```

Only two branches (loop and check) is easier for the branch predictor and the contiguous memory optimizes the prefetcher.

Obvious variations are checking bitboards[0] to [5] for white pieces only and [6] to [11] for black pieces only.

A more subtle variant:

```
uint64_t bitboards[13];
bitboards[12] = ~uint64_t(0);
for (int i = 0; /* NO TEST*/ ; ++i)
{
     if (bitboards[i] && bit_check) return i;
}
```

Instead of returning -1 for empty, this will return 12 (the sentinel value). However, this replaces the conditional loop branch with a faster unconditional branch. It also means that the return value is always `int i`.

Another unrelated optimization is to recognize that pawns are the most common pieces, so it's more efficient to use `bitboards[0]` for white pawns and either `bitboards[1]` or `bitboards[6]` for black pawns, depending on whether you interleave black or white pieces.

[edit]
If you have a separate bitboard for `color`, you then do not need two bitboards for white pawns and black pawns. Instead, have a single bitboard for pawns. To check for a black pawn, AND the two values. (`bit_check & color & bitboard[0]`). To check for a white pawn, invert the color (`bit_check & ~color & bitboard[0]`)

Comment: I've already used the simple optimisations your mentioned. That is, I checked if it is empty first, followed by pawns, then rooks, knights, bishops, queens and then finally for kings.

Nevertheless, I don't see how I could have missed it. Great solution.

Comment: I think you mean i++, by the way. bitboards[0] isn't being checked at all with ++i!

Comment: @ShreyasVinod: You may want to pull out your C++ book again. The expression used inside the loop is just plain `i`. And the `for` loop ignores the value of the third part; it only checks the boolean value of the middle part. I could write `for(int i = 0; i != 12; ++i * 7)` and it would do exactly the same. Multiplying an unused value by 7 still leaves it unused. But if you don't believe me, add a `std::cout << i << std::endl;` inside the loop.

Comment: Huh, interesting, you're right, my bad. I expected it to increment prior to the condition check.

Comment: First, you never actually need to check all 12 bitboards in one loop... In practice, this is a loop of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. I just unroll it but even if you don't the optimizer would, so avoiding the conditional doesn't actually help.

Comment: @VoidStar: Keep in mind that unrolling a loop with early exit (`return i`)  is possible but not so trivial. I'll happily let the compiler decide if that's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the slowest operation for a bitboard. However, you rarely have to perform it.

I see you are maintaining a bitwise 'or' of all white pieces, `white` and a bitwise or of all black pieces, `black`. Using those, you can quickly reject moves onto your own pieces and easily detect capture.

In the somewhat unlikely event of a capture, you have to test for up to 5 of the 6 enemy piece bitboards, because king capture should have already been ruled out. Also, this is not as tedious as you imagine; on a 64 bit system, each mask is only 1 operation per bitboard and then a compare, so 10 integer operations. `And`/`Or` are some of the lightest operations on the processor. Maintaining the `Piece[64]` alone costs more time than this does.

I believe there is no other case (within the engine code) where you need to get a pieceID from a given square.

The major advantage of the bitboards is the move generation and positional analysis. There is nothing that compares, so you'll be maintaining this structure no matter what.

Comment: If you look at the code, `white` and `black` are already are in the mix. And I agree, bitwise operations are a breeze for modern ALUs.

Comment: Hm, thinking about it a little bit, you're quite right as captures are somewhat rare in the move generation process.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's efficient to have a bitboard for "all white pieces" since it's trivially generated.

Comment: It is, i've measured it different ways. it gets read as part of a number of early outs and other cases, and in the positional analysis code too.